# Using Degree Symbol in Times-New-Roman Font with Itextpdf

Tags: java, fonts, itext

I am creating a PDF file using itextpdf and need the degree symbol. I know it exists in the Times-New-Roman font. Using the unicode string works for Swing but not with itext. It just displays the literal string.

```
Font headerFont = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 10.f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

I have my degree symbol set in a variable:

```
tempScale="\\u00B0C";
```

I add the string to my PDF thus:

```
table.addCell(createCell("Actual\nTemperature\n"+tempScale,headerFont));
```

I read about adding basefont.IDENTITY_H to access all symbols in the font but it is unclear how I incorporate that into the Times-New-Roman font instance. Can someone tell me how to get the degree symbol displayed? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't escape the unicode character

```
String tempScale = "\u00B0C";
```

Comment: That was it. Something weird must have been going on as I had it that way originally and it did not work. I went on to other things and made a host of seemingly unrelated changes to my code. I just go back to this now so something I thought was unrelated must have fixed it. Thanks.